# Does a generalization of the Teichmüller-character for non-prime arguments exist?

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, p-adic-number-theory, teichmueller-theory

Rereading an older article on Fermat-quotients in which I'd applied some p-adic-rationale I find now, that my method for the representation of bases $b$ which allow high fermat-quotients $b_{p,m}^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod {p^m}$ as digit-string in the numbersystem to base $p$ is just the "[Teichmüller-character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teichm%C3%BCller_character)" (or "-representation"(?)).

Because I wanted to analyze things further I thought to apply that procedures to composites numbers $n$ as well instead only to primes $p$ - at least so far as possible. However, the Teichmüller-character is only defined for prime modules $p$ (and for instance its implementation in Pari/GP gives wrong results for non-prime arguments). So my question (to prevent attempts to reinvent the wheel or trying to quadrature the circle) is

> ***Q1:*** Is there a generalization of the Teichmüller-character to non-prime arguments known/possible?

and optimally:

> Q2: how could I implement this algorithmically?

Comment: I've a basic routine for this for the prime-arguments which seems to work even for composite (but squarefree) bases, but for composite $n$ containing primefactors to second or higher powers this method runs sometimes in impossible inversion in the modular computation (and also not all residue-classes can be used). So likely any generalization has some limitations/restrictions, but I hope that this might come out to be systematic with a not too complicated pattern.

*Background: the discussion of the fermat-quotient-computation with a p-adic analogy can be seen* [here](http://go.helms-net.de/math/expdioph/fermatquotients.pdf) *(mathematical derivation see pg 9)*

*Ps.: I don't know whether the tag "teichmueller-theory" is really appropriate here, feel free to remove this if it is misleading*